# Core Data: Compound Indexes are not getting created on a child entity

Tags: ios, entity-framework, sqlite, core-data, indexing

Here is the situation: I have a parent - child Core Data model relationship. I have some fields on the child entity which I order by using sort descriptors on a fetch request. I have added them on the Indexes list on the Entity section of the Data Model Inspector like field1,field2.

However, when setting -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1, I cannot see the compound index being created. Further more, I was able to get the SQLite generated file, and all I can see are the single field indexes created for other purposes, but not the compound ones.

Is there a limitation by doing this on a child entity? Has anyone achieved creating compound indexes on child entities? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up creating a simple Core Data project from scratch with just a Parent and a Child entities just to see what happened when I selected and deselected Parent as Parent Entity of the Child entity in the Core Data model.

By using `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` I was able to see that compound indexes were being created only when the Child entity didn't have Parent as the Parent Entity.

BTW, I was running iOS 8.3.

As a side note, I debugged the Core Data code, and it seems a `createIndexesForEntity:` method of a private class `NSSQLConnection`, was being called. However, at the very beginning of the method code, it calls a method `isRootEntity` of another private class `NSSQLEntity`. When that returns NO, it skips the method code and returns without doing anything.

This feature was so important for me that I ended up removing the Parent Entity setting from all the entities present in the project's Core Data model.